# Starling AS3 -- How To Use Bitmap Objects in SWC

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, displayobject, starling-framework

I'm trying to see how Starling could benefit the applications I build using as3.  My knowledge thus far  of Starling is that it only uses bitmap objects not symbol objects.  How do I take a `BitmapData` class and create an starling `Image` out of it.

*This bitmap was a symbol in flash that was converted into bitmap.  It then had its properties modified to export for as3*

Say there is a **Ship BitmapData class** in a swc.
According to Starlings documentation of how it handles other bitmap like a png, I would think I should be able to do this.

```
 var myShip:Image = Image.fromBitmap(new Ship());
```

This of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fromBitmap() expects to receive a bitmap object but here you are passing in a BitmapData Class. And Image class requires a texture.

Also your syntax is slightly incorrect.

NB. There is Texture.fromBitmap and Texture.fromBitmapData.

Although I haven't tried accessing assets from a swc you could try:

```
var myShip:Image = new Image(Texture.fromBitmapData(new Ship());
```

Perhaps try to get the Image appearing first before attempting to access the swc bitmapData

```
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, false, 0xFF0000);
var myShip:Image = new Image(Texture.fromBitmapData(bd);
addChild(myShip); //should display a red square
```